# How do I change a field to a negative based on another field's value in SQL

Tags: sql

With the below statement I would like amount to be negative if `[Invoice_Type_Code] = 'c'`, and if is not then it is positive.

```
SELECT [Invoice_Amount]
FROM [Forefront].[dbo].[VN_GL_DISTRIBUTION_HEADER_MC]
WHERE [Vendor_Code] ='  UnitedEL' and
[Date_List1]  > '2011-12-31' and
[Date_List1] < '2012-02-01' and
[Company_Code] = 'tmg'
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your RDBMS, using `CASE` could work -- most RDBMS should support it:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN  Invoice_Type_Code = 'C' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * Invoice_Amount
FROM [Forefront].[dbo].[VN_GL_DISTRIBUTION_HEADER_MC]
where [Vendor_Code] ='  UnitedEL' and
[Date_List1]  > '2011-12-31' and [Date_List1] < '2012-02-01' and
[Company_Code] = 'tmg'
```

This assumes all Invoice_Amounts are positive.  If they aren't positive and you still need negative values, use the `ABS` function and alter your case statement slightly.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c5f4/1).

Good luck.

Comment: Deleted mine but just as a note some RDBMS (e.g. Sql Server) will support `SELECT CASE WHEN [Invoice_Type_Code] = "c" THEN -[Invoice_Amount] ELSE [Invoice_Amount] END` removing the multiplication of -1/1